# VB Loop for MS Access that adds numbers

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm new to coding with Access. I'm wanting to create a Do While Until loop that compares the amounts of two tables. One table has a record with customer numbers with the total amount for each customer number and then another table that has all detail line items with amounts for the items for each customer.

**Example:**

*Summary*

```
 CustID | Total  |              
   1234 | $20.00 |          
   2345 | $40.00 |
```

*Detail*

```
 CustID | DocNo | Amount | Included |
   1234 | 0000  | $15.00 |          |
   1234 | 1111  | $5.00  |          |
   1234 | 2222  | $3.00  |          |
```

I wanted to be able to execute the loop and then update the Included column to "Yes" to all applicable line items whose accumulated sum added to the total in the *Summary* table.

So the example above would update the first and second rows of the *Detail* table to "Yes" and then move on to the next CustID, because the first two row Amounts totaled to $20.00 - the amount in the *Summary* table. The last record in the detail table will not be updated to anything, because it does not apply. The good thing about the order of these records is that the records that will be labeled "Yes" will be the first cumulative set of records; not every other record, or random records. There are no fixed number of records for each total, it varies - therefore, I need the loop.

Also, does anyone have a recommendation for how to best learn VB/VBA for Access and Excel? I only understand SQL and I'm trying to enhance my coding skills, so I'm not having to manually subtotal these amounts and then delete the 30,000 non applicable records in an Excel spreadsheet.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the totals always found by walking up the items in DocNo order? In other words, in your example, could 1111 be $3 and 2222 be $5, making 1111 the odd one out? If they aren't always found by summing the earliest DocNos, you'll have the problem of what to do when there is more than one match (e.g., if both 1111 and 2222 were $5 in the example).

Comment: It's always going to be the earliest documents. It won't ever skip over any documents.

Comment: +1 for presentation.  I appreciate your desire to learn VBA, but why would you not use SQL?  VBA recordset processing is efficient only when SQL is not.  (I see the need for VBA when it's time to deal with the spreadsheet, of course.)

Comment: Are Summary and Detail linked tables to SQL in Access or are they plain Access tables?

Comment: could you be interested by the sql solution also?

Answer (score 0):

I've worked out a first approach, using DAO, your tables are supposed to be **Summary** and **Detail**:

```
Sub sof20295931SummaryDetail()

  Dim lCustID0 As Long
  Dim dblDetailTotal As Double, dblSummaryTotal As Double
  Dim strSQL As String
  Dim rst0 As DAO.Recordset, rst As DAO.Recordset

'
' get summary recordset:
'
  strSQL = "SELECT CustID, Total" _
    & " FROM Summary" _
    & " ORDER BY CustID;"
  Set rst0 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

'
' get detail recordset:
'
  strSQL = "SELECT CustID, DocNo, Amount, Included" _
    & " FROM Detail" _
    & " ORDER BY CustID,DocNo;"
  Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

  lCustID0 = rst0!CustID
  dblSummaryTotal = rst0!Total
  dblDetailTotal = 0

  '
  ' check the recordset of the Detail:
  '
  Do While (Not rst.EOF)
    '
    ' change CustID:
    '
    If (rst!CustID > lCustID0) Then
      rst0.MoveNext
      lCustID0 = rst0!CustID
      dblSummaryTotal = rst0!Total
      dblDetailTotal = 0
    End If
    '
    ' sum up:
    '
    dblDetailTotal = dblDetailTotal + rst!amount
    '
    ' modify record:
    '
    rst.Edit
    '
    If (dblDetailTotal <= dblSummaryTotal) Then
      rst!Included = "Yes"
    Else
      rst!Included = Null
    End If
    '
    rst.Update
    '
    ' go to the next record:
    '
    rst.MoveNext
  Loop
  '
  ' destruct objects:
  '
  rst0.Close
  Set rst0 = Nothing
  '
  rst.Close
  Set rst = Nothing
End Sub
```

My Windows Locale used Euro Money format, here is the **Summary** table:

[image]

And **Detail** table in which I added some extra records:

[image]

**Detail** after modification:

[image]

Comment: Good answer, though I'd personally change `Included` to a `Yes/No` field in Access-speak (or if nulls are needed, an integral field). Also, an aside, but I am curious why you have the `Close` calls and assignments to `Nothing` at the end. If the reference counting of Access VBA objects is broken, there will be memory leaks everywhere and I can't see how you can ever trust the software; conversely, if it isn't, then explicit 'tidying up' like that is pointless (or so it seems to me).

Comment: @Chris Rolliston, the OP quoted "Yes", he might want string/text. In SQL Server, Yes/No (-1/0) field does not exist, but rather 0/1 field (bit), so it's somehow incompatible. I agree with you, .Close and set Nothing are useless at the end of the Sub. But the explicit destruction of objects in the middle of Sub/Function permits us to gain RAM for the execution thread that follows.

Comment: @jacouch - well, I meant 'whatever is the Boolean field type (if there is one, otherwise an integer where 0 is treated as meaning False or No)'. The string literal 'Yes' should be how the data is presented rather than the data itself IMO, though I appreciate the OP conflated the two.

Comment: @Chris Rolliston, I share at 100% your preference. If I were OP, I would change Included to bit in SQL Server, as Access uses linked table: OP comes from SQL Server World...

Comment: Wow thanks for the responses and the solutions. I did think of using SQL for the solution, but was afraid of pulling records out of order. Using a loop made sense to me at the time. I did however use SQL to fix my problem the day after. I created a module that created a running total for each CustID. Then I created an AutoNumber field for the Detail table, then selected * that had an ID <= the ID of the RunningTotal WHERE Summary.[Amount] = Detail.[Running Total]. Any type of field for the Included field would've been fine and I'll definitely take your advice going forward. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

*Since no reply on whether a more SQL-centered approach is okay, here it is.*

The field `Included` does not logically belong in Detail, but in Summary.  If you want to keep it in Detail, using SQL is a challenge: you can't use the aggregate function `Sum()` and also update values.  But if you move `Included` to Summary, SQL is the natural solution.  I would recommend this approach.

**qrySummary** (to be nested in second query below)

```
SELECT CustID, Sum([Total]) AS CustomerTotal 
FROM tblDetail GROUP BY CustID;
```

**qryValidate**

```
UPDATE tblSummary LEFT JOIN qrySummary ON tblSummary.CustID = qrySummary.CustID 
SET tblSummary.Included = 
  IIf([qrySummary].[CustomerTotal]=[tblSummary].[Amount],True,False);
```

To follow through on the spreadsheet, you will need to view `Included` at the detail level; this will require a query that joins Detail and Summary.

Comment: 'The field `Included` does not logically belong in `Detail`, but in `Summary`' - I may have got the wrong idea, but my understanding is that this is some sort of reconciliation excercise: which entries in `Detail` have already been accounted for in `Summary`? As such, `Included` logically belongs in `Detail`, not `Summary`.

Comment: Your thinking is right, I'm sure.  The "logical" reason I'm using is based in the data-normalization principle that data should not be redundant; it should be held in fewer places wherever possible..  In this case a record is tagged as "okay" based on its membership in a group, and the group is identified via the header; so I prefer store the data in the header.  This database application may not benefit in some classic way from a normalized structure at this point (though it may), but it happens that normalized structure is also what will facilitate use of SQL.

Comment: my assummption was that the data is from elsewhere given the OP's reference to Excel... but I may be wrong. If the database is itself the original datasource, then I'd add a foreign key to Detail that references Summary.

Comment: "a foreign key to Detail that references Summary" -- that would be `CustID`.

Comment: Well, I'd have Payment (PaymentID, CustID, Total) and PaymentDetail (DetailID, PaymentID, Amount), with Summary now a view/select query that groups on CustID...